# Send Mail Using Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, email, smtp, lumen

**Mail.php**

```
return [
 'driver' =>'smtp',
 'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
 //'port' => 587,
 'port' =>465,
 //'encryption' =>'tls',
 'encryption' =>'ssl',
 'username' => 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
 'password' => 'xxxxxxx',
 // 'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
 'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t',
 'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',
        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],
];
```

**Controller**

```
$data = []; // Empty array

        Mail::send('email.credentials', $data, function($message)
        {
            $message->to('xxxxxx@gmail.com', 'Jon Doe')->subject('Welcome!');
        });
```

**Error**

> Swift_TransportException Connection could not be established with host
>   smtp.gmail.com [A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

I Tried...

- Change ssl / tls
- Change the ports
- Add `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.3|~6.0"` in composer.json
- Add a new line in StreamBuffer.php

  > $options = array_merge($options, array('ssl' => array('verify_peer' =>
  >   false,'verify_peer_name' => false,'allow_self_signed' => true )));

Please help .

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

**1. Require illuminate/mail**

Make sure you’re using the same version as your underlying framework (i.e. if you’re on Lumen v. 5.3, use `composer require illuminate/mail "5.3.*"`).

> ```
> composer require illuminate/mail "5.5.*"
> ```

**2. Set up Lumen `bootstrap/app.php`**

First, open your `bootstrap.php` and uncomment the following lines:

```
$app->withFacades();
$app->register(App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class);
```

Also, add the following line below the last line you uncommented:

```
$app->configure('services');
```

This will allow you to define a ‘services’ config file and setup your mail service. Now I know that normally configuration is done in the .env file with Lumen, and we’ll use that shortly, but first we’ll need to write a small config file to map to the `.env` file.

**3. Create your configuration files**

Create a new folder at the root level of your install called config(if it doesn’t already exist). In the config folder, create two new files, one named services.php and another named `**mail.php**.`

In the **`services.php`** file paste the following:

```
<?php
return [
    'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
    ],
];
```

Lastly, add the following to your .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=<your-mailgun-domain>
MAILGUN_SECRET=<your-mailgun-api-key>
```

Make sure you replace those sneaky placeholders with your actual key and domain. If you’re not using Mailgun, you can always use the other mail providers Mail comes with; have a look at the docs if you plan on using a different provider, they are all easy to set up once you’re at this point.

**4. Send Email!**

To send an email, use one of the following in your classes (depending on your preference):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

    $data = []; // Empty array

    Mail::send('email.credentials', $data, function($message)
    {
        $message->to('xxxxxx@gmail.com', 'Jon Doe')->subject('Welcome!');
    });
```

Finally, don’t forget to read the  [Laravel Mail docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail) for more info on how to use this great library.

Comment: I tried but its not working, my comany network is with a proxy is any issue......?

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned on `2 layers security` in your `Google account` (email address you config in `.env` file) which uses to send email.